# TypeError in Python occurs in Python Shell but not script?

Tags: python

I don't know why the following simple lines work when I write a script.py and run that script but does not work in the Python shell:

```
random = [1,2,3]
iter = iter(random) 
print (next(iter))
```

The output for this is of course: `1` when running script 
But if I enter each line in the Python shell, I get:

```
'str_iterator' object not callable
```

after `iter = iter(random)`

Why is that so?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: this works fine in python 3.7.0.
iter only exist in python 2.2 and later: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: @Swift: Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned to the name `iter` the result of calling the built in function `iter`. This will now not let you call `iter` again in the REPL.

So almost certainly, in your shell session you've done:

```
iter = iter(some_string)
```

Since it is a built-in, just do `del iter` **and don't use built in functions as variable names**

Comment: This doesn't explain the error message they're getting.

Comment: @jwodder I would bet money that in the REPL they already assigned a string iterator to iter, and then never restarted the session